# Looking for a jQuery Slider with 3 Lines

Tags: jquery, html, css

i´m looking for a Slider for a website with three Lines to switch/slide with text or images. 
Anybody know these offers switching my body with another head, or my legs with another.... the slider could like a cube thats switch.

it dont have to be full size, only centered in the middle with a width of 400 to 600 and a height of 400 to 600 px (for all three sliders) or so.

the slider should look like this:

< prev   [img/txt]   next >

< prev   [img/txt]   next >

< prev   [img/txt]   next >

And if these three lines could interact it would be the greatest thing ever ;-)

we would like make a "configurator" but with no function, only for information, so in first step choose a location, in second step choose a food, and in third choose eg a dj or band. The interaction with these three lines only should be the active slide to easy read for contact form or other stuff. no more.

do anybody knows a slider i´m looking for? I have searched hours but don´t find the right one. 
Thanks.

Comment: Try slick.js - it's highly customizable

Comment: Looks great, put three slides on page. but do you have an idea for "read" the active slide of the three sliders?

Comment: Slick comes with methods that allow you to read data-attributes and such. What you described is completly possible and pretty easy to achieve with slick

Comment: What i dont understand, why vote down this question??? it contains description what i need, and i asked for some reasons because i dont know the right plugin or code, and now vote it down?  i have not asked for the finished code or "hey, could someone code this for me", i asked for sliders that could build with my question... 
sorry, couldn´t understand this.... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `slick` for this. I wrote up an example on how to use it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows:true
  });
  $("#final").click(function () {
    console.log("Current slides:");
    console.log($('.slide1').slick('slickCurrentSlide'));
    console.log($('.slide2').slick('slickCurrentSlide'));
    console.log($('.slide3').slick('slickCurrentSlide'));
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background:black;
}

.sliderContainer {
  padding:40px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="sliderContainer">
  <div class="slider slide3">
    <div>your content1</div>
    <div>your content2</div>
    <div>your content3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider slide2">
    <div>your content1</div>
    <div>your content2</div>
    <div>your content3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider slide1">
    <div>your content1</div>
    <div>your content2</div>
    <div>your content3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="final">Finalize</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ["jQuery lightSlider"](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html)

Comment: Thx, i think slick is the right way... :-) the sample looks great. LightSlider is good, too. But i think will realize it with slick.

Answer (score 0):

Thx to Jonathan and special thanks to fiffe. :-) Slick looks fine. And nfn neil great for your sample. I have seen the after change and bevore change events, think after change is the best to my way.

Btw: i´m reading questions and answers for a long time to get answers for my ways in c# or jquery, now i´ve posted MY first question and within minutes became good answers. great network with great people here.